# Convert class 'pandas.tslib.Timedelta' to string when export to excel

Tags: excel, datetime, pandas, string-formatting, timedelta

Initial dataframe:

```
arrivalTime        
0   2016-01-12 06:35:42
2   2016-01-12 06:54:02
3   2016-01-12 07:01:43
4   2016-01-12 07:02:28
5   2016-01-12 07:12:29
6   2016-01-12 07:18:41
```

On data I apply this function:

```
def function(df):
    df['arrivalTime_cal'] = pd.to_datetime(df['arrivalTime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df['diff_time'] = df['arrivalTime_cal'].diff().fillna(0)
    del df['arrivalTime_cal']
    return df
```

and I get these results (corrects in ipython):

```
diff_time  
0  00:00:00  
1  00:04:37  
2  00:13:43  
3  00:07:41  
4  00:00:45
```

when export to excel that result change format:

```
arrivalTime             diff_time
0   2016-01-12 06:35:42 0
1   2016-01-12 06:40:19 0,003206019
2   2016-01-12 06:54:02 0,009525463
3   2016-01-12 07:01:43 0,005335648
4   2016-01-12 07:02:28 0,000520833
```

How do I keep the string format in Excel?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC then you can just cast the type to `str` and then `split` the str:

```
In [53]:
df['diff_time'].astype(str).str.split().str[-1].str.rsplit('.').str[0]

Out[53]:
index
0    00:00:00
2    00:18:20
3    00:07:41
4    00:00:45
5    00:10:01
6    00:06:12
dtype: object
```

Breaking the above down into steps, cast to `str` using `astype`:

```
In [54]:
df['diff_time'].astype(str)

Out[54]:
index
0    0 days 00:00:00.000000000
2    0 days 00:18:20.000000000
3    0 days 00:07:41.000000000
4    0 days 00:00:45.000000000
5    0 days 00:10:01.000000000
6    0 days 00:06:12.000000000
Name: diff_time, dtype: object
```

now split (default character will be spaces) and take just the last split element which is the time component:

```
In [55]:
df['diff_time'].astype(str).str.split().str[-1]

Out[55]:
index
0    00:00:00.000000000
2    00:18:20.000000000
3    00:07:41.000000000
4    00:00:45.000000000
5    00:10:01.000000000
6    00:06:12.000000000
dtype: object
```

Now `rsplit` and take the time minus hte microseconds

```
In [56]:
df['diff_time'].astype(str).str.split().str[-1].str.rsplit('.')

Out[56]:
index
0    [00:00:00, 000000000]
2    [00:18:20, 000000000]
3    [00:07:41, 000000000]
4    [00:00:45, 000000000]
5    [00:10:01, 000000000]
6    [00:06:12, 000000000]
dtype: object
```

You can see that the converted values are indeed `str`:

```
In [57]:
df['diff_time'].astype(str).str.split().str[-1].str.rsplit('.').str[0][0]

Out[57]:
'00:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's a commen task to convert from timedelta to str, this functionality should be build in in pandas.